# Taylor Series Expansion of $f(x) = 2/(1-x)$ centered at $x=3$. Give the interval of convergence.

Tags: calculus

Find the Taylor Expansion for the function f(x) = 2/(1-x) centered at x = 3.
   Give the interval of convergence for this series.

So if I remember correctly, we first take the first four or so derivatives.

$f(x) = 2/(1-x)$

$f'(x) = 2/(1-x)^2$

$f''(x) = 4/(1-x)^3$

$f'''(x) = 12/(1-x)^4$

$f''''(x) = 48/(1-x)^5$

---

Now at x = 3 for those derivatives are:

$f(3) = -1$

$f'(3) = .5$

$f''(3) = -.5$

$f'''(3) = (3/4)$

$f''''(3) = -(3/2)$

---

Is this the Taylor Expansion?

$f(x) = -1 + (1/2)(x-3) - (1/2)( (x-3)^{2} / 2! ) + (3/4)( (x-3)^{3} / 3! ) ...$

I need to find a general solution for this, but I can't really nail down a pattern. To do the interval of convergence portion I need to figure out that pattern so this is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to take $y=x-3$ so $x=y+3$ and then
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{1-x}=\frac{-2}{2+y}=\frac{-1}{1+(y/2)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^n$$

The ratio test gives $R=2$ so the interval of convergence centred at $3$ is $(1,5)$.

Comment: How would have I had known to do that? I thought that we were supposed to take derivatives, evaluate them at the centered point, then find a general solution.

Comment: @Ozera: Your way is the methodical approach that will work in every case. This answer uses a shortcut based on the series
$$
\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots
$$
People build up a repertoire of these sorts of series, and they usually prove useful.

Comment: @Ozera So add this method  to your toolbox:-)

Comment: Ah this is a very cool method. Definitely remembering it, but could you show me what I was doing wrong? Or how I was supposed to find the general solution? Sorry

Comment: @Ozera Your method is correct but just try to write the coefficients of the derivatives of $f$ with the factorial to facilitate the simplification since  finaly you divide by $n!$. Right?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I find it to be: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1/(-2)^n) * (x-3)^{n} / n!$. Why do you not include the $n!$ ?

Comment: No prove by induction that $f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{2n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$ and then we find 
$$f^{(n)}(3)=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n!}{2^n}$$